# Stack trace shows exception at wrong position

Tags: java, debugging, exception, remote-debugging

I'm dealing with a null pointer exception for which I have a stack trace. In my log files, stack traces provide line numbers. It seems like the line numbers on the exception's stack trace are wrong. This is in a project that's new to me.

When I look at the source code at the specified lines, there is sometimes no code (a blank line) or an end curly brace (`}`), so I'm unable to find the cause of the `NullPointerException`.

> java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   com.test.AddProductServlet.list(AddProductServlet.java:776)
>     at
>   com.test.AddProductServlet.list(AddProductServlet.java:436)
>     at
>   com.test.AddProductServlet.routeAction(AddProductServlet.java:263)
>     at
>   com.test.AddProductServlet.onService(AddProductServlet.java:145)
>     at
>   com.test.MqServlet.service(MqServlet.java:500)
>     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

I inserted breakpoints before the lines from the stack trace (i.e. 770, 430 and 260) and still can't find the cause of the exception.

I am using Eclipse Helios with Java 1.6.0_16. Is this an Eclipse problem? If so, what changes are required?

I redeployed the project but still have the same problem.

What do I do next? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I suppose you're doing remote debug. Please make sure that you re-deploy correctly, then restart the server and the re-attach the debugger and check again..

Comment: make sure the code fully compiled and deployed.

Comment: @denis.solonenka Thanks for reply. I am debugging remote java app. I again re-deploy correctly and started server. Still same stack tarce mentioned above.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy Thanks for reply. Yes code is fully compiled and deployed. Running well but at particular position gives exception (NullPointerException) :(

Comment: @Vaibhav Bhalke ok, then you should check if you have the freshest code in the eclipse - sync from vcs if any or hit f5 on the project to get the latest changes from the disk

Comment: The source code that you're looking at is not the source code that was used to produce the compiled code that's throwing the error. There could be many things causing this, so without knowing anything about your build environment or your workflow I can't say for sure. Just make sure that when you redeploy, you re-compile *everything*.

Comment: @VaibhaV I am facing same problem, can you tell what you did to solve it??

Comment: By the way, if anyone else is still using Java 1.6, you should have upgraded ~10 years ago.   And 1.6.0_16 is nearly 15 years out of date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am using eclipse helios, Java 1.6.0_16. Is it eclipse problem ?

No.  The JVM creates the stack traces, not Eclipse.  (It is *theoretically* possible that Eclipse's Java compiler could insert incorrect line numbers into the `.class` files ... but hundreds of thousands of Java developers would have noticed by now ...)

> I redeployed project still same problem.  what to do next ? How to solve this problem?

As @Mike says *"The source code that you're looking at is not the source code that was used to produce the compiled code that's throwing the error."*

It therefore is either a build, deployment or configuration problem:

1. In Eclipse, do an F5 refresh, clean and build the project, then redeploy and see if that fixes the line numbers.
2. Manually shutdown the server, delete the deployed WAR file and expanded directory, redeploy the WAR file and restart the server.
3. Search the deployed webapp, including all JAR files to find all copies of `AddProductServlet.class`.

   - If there is more than one, figure out why.
   - If there is only one, check that it is identical to the one that you just built, and if it is not, find out why.
4. Use `Ant` or whatever to build the code outside of Eclipse, then deploy that.  (This will eliminate any possibility that it is Eclipse's fault ...)